# vector states from elementary tensors $h\otimes k\in H\otimes K$ separate all of $\mathbb{B}(H\otimes K)$

Tags: operator-theory, tensor-products, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

In the book "C* algebras and finite dimensional approximations",there is a statement in the proof of lemma4.1.8,$A\otimes B\subset\mathbb{B}(H\otimes K)$ and vector states from elementary tensors $h\otimes k\in H\otimes K$ separate all of $\mathbb{B}(H\otimes K)$,Who can give me a little hints on how to prove the statement,thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to show is that if $T\in B(H\otimes K)$ satisfies $T(h\otimes k)=0$ for all $h\in H$, $k\in K$, then $T=0$.

This is straighforward: given $\xi\in H\otimes K$, we may write 
$$
\xi=\sum_{k,j} \alpha_{kj}\,e_k\otimes f_j
$$
for orthonormal bases $\{e_k\}$ of $H$ and $\{f_j\}$ of $K$. Then, since $T$ is bounded, 
$$
T\xi=\sum_{k,j} \alpha_{kj}\,T(e_k\otimes f_j)=0. 
$$
So $T=0$.

Comment: i don't understand the meaning of vector states from elementary tensors.My thought:For any $T\in B(H\otimes K)$ ,we can find a vector state $\phi$ such that  $\phi(T)\neq 0$ .

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you are asking. You mean to ask what a vector state is?

Comment: Yes.what is the definiton of vector state.

Comment: A vector state is a state of the form $a\longmapsto \langle a\xi,\xi\rangle$ for a unit vector $\xi$.

Comment: By the definition,does it mean that vector states from elementary tensors $h\otimes k\in H\otimes K$ has the form $a\longmapsto \langle ah\otimes k,h\otimes k\rangle$?

Comment: No, they have the form $$\langle a\left(\sum_j h_j\otimes k_j\right),\sum_j h_j\otimes k_j\rangle =\sum_{s,j} \langle a(h_j\otimes k_j),h_s\otimes k_s\rangle.$$